# What is the include path for cblas.h on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, blas

I'm trying to use the blas/cblas in the Accelerate framework. (OS X 10.13 if it matters)
I have found the linker option "-framework Accelerate" but I can't find the compiler option that makes "cblas.h" found.

I'm not using Xcode or so: straight clang in an xterm driven by a makefile.

So what's the "-I" include path?

Answer (score 8):

It is somewhere around here:

`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/`

I know this really sounds fishy. This does change from version to version of OSX / XCode ...

But its really easy to find where it's at on your specific installation:

Open Finder and type in in the upper right corner into the search field and type `cblas.h` et voila!

This I quickly hacked and should compile as below on your mac:

```
#include <cblas.h>

#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> class matrix {

public: 
  matrix(const size_t& n) : n_(n), data_(n_*n_) {}
  T* data() { return data_.data(); }
  const T* data() const { return data_.data(); }
  std::vector<T>& vec() { return data_; }
  size_t const& n() const { return n_; }
  const std::vector<T>& vec() const { return data_; }

private:
  size_t n_;
  std::vector<T> data_;

};

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd()); 
std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(-1.0, 1.0);

template<typename T> matrix<T> random(const size_t& n) {
  matrix<T> m(n);
  std::generate_n(m.vec().begin(), m.vec().size(), std::bind(dis, gen));
  return m;

}

template<typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const matrix<T>& m) {
  auto const n = m.n();
  size_t j = 0;
  for (auto const& i : m.vec()) {    
    o << i <<" ";
    if(j++%n == n-1) o << std::endl;
  }
  return o;
}

int main () {

  const size_t n = 4;
  matrix<float> A = random<float>(n), B = random<float>(n), C(n);
  std::cout << A << std::endl << B << std::endl;

  cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, n, n, n,
              1.0, A.data(), n, B.data(), n, 0.0, C.data(), n);

  std::cout << C << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

`clang++ -O3 -std=c++11 cblas_test.cpp -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/ -framework Accelerate -o cblas_test`